# How to open a MS doc on browser?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have worked with Microsoft graph for a bit and i was able to figure out how to get specific document to download from sharepoint.

The problem i am having now is that i want to open the document on the browser that i am using (assuming that i have access to sharepoint and that file) after i download it (or if possible without downloading it locally).

I have searched around a bit with no success. The website i have found describes the APIs that i can use to get the data, but not how to display it on the browser (On ready only mode).

Any pointers would be nice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can get that file by using the below call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45/drives/b!loMXwUXY-ka8DEU9KVHa1R6a7hkdAPFInuiwrf3lTkWmzNPKD2ILQLNdmX03mXTy/Items/01LPJ34YX44MG4S6NWQZE2A4VZZ6JZNWIS` modify itemid, driveid and siteid. You will be getting a 'weburl' property in that item object. Use it to open in browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `DriveItem` resources include two relevant properties for this, [`webUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) and [`@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#instance-attributes).

If you're looking to download the file, the `downloadUrl` provides a short-lived (1 hour) pre-authenticated link (i.e. you don't need to authenticate to use the Uri).

If you're looking to simply open the file directly, you can follow the `webUrl`. It will open the document in the browser using it's associated editor (Word, Excel, etc.). Users can also opt to open the document in the desktop version of the app (if they have it installed).

```
{
  "id": "string (identifier)",
  "createdBy": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet"},
  "createdDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "eTag": "string",
  "lastModifiedBy": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet"},
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "name": "string",
  "parentReference": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.itemReference"},
  "webUrl": "string",
  "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "url",
}
```